# Change row names based on row number

Tags: r, rename, rows

I have a column with 82 rows, which are completely filled with NA's, called 'treatment'.
I want to change the rows 1-21 and 43-64 to 'Control', and the rows 22-42 and 65-82 to 'Fluox'.

How can I achieve this without having to define every row by itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
NAME_OF_DATASET$treatment[c(1:21, 43:64)] = 'Control'
NAME_OF_DATASET$treatment[c(22:42, 65:82)] = 'Fluox'
```